# Knockout if else Statement

Tags: knockout.js

I've a graph chart like below made using css and knockout.js (binding)

Depending on the value of the data, I need to size the height of the bars by selecting different css classes.

I've tried to use the knockout if statement below:

```
The <!-- ko --> and <!-- /ko -->
```

However, this doesn't meet my requirement as I need  something like below:

```
     <ul data-bind="foreach: ArrayData">
      <!-- ko if: value >= 300 and value <=250 -->
            <li class="height300Css">
        <!-- /ko -->
       <!-- ko if: value >= 200 and value <=300 -->
            <li class="height200Css">
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
```

Could someone suggest any alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a computed observable to your view model that returns the correct css class, then use the "attr" binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html).

Or use the "css" binding - but that requires you to have the whole selection logic in the view file.

---

Example code:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    // ....

    self.cssClass = ko.computed(function() {
        var value = self.value();
        if (value >= 300 && value <= 250) {
            return 'height300Css';
        }
        // ...
    };
};
```

And in the view:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { class: cssClass }">
```

---

If you're dealing with an array of objects, you can either add the computed observable to those objects or you can add a normal function to the view model and call it during the foreach loop.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(...);

    self.getCssClass = function(item) {
        var value = item.value();
        // ...
    };
};
```

And in the view:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { class: $root.getCssClass($data) }">
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/awacew

Comment: Thanks @Niko, that would work if it's just one object. In my case it's an array of objects. I'm using foreach on outer div first. Have updated the question.

Comment: So either extend those objects in that array, or use a normal function and hand over the current item. I'm gonna add an example to my answer!

Comment: One little addition use "attr: { 'class': $root.getCssClass($data) }", otherwise it will cause an error in IE <=7. As i remember this issue is planned to be fixed but in 2.0 version it's still exist. Haven't checked 2.1

Comment: You still need the quotes around `class` in IE, but 2.1 does fix the problem that the `class` attribute didn't work in IE<7 (and you had to also include `className`).

Comment: Knockout 2.2 will allow you to use the `css` binding instead of `attr/class` to set a dynamic class. So then you could do `data-bind="css: cssClass"`. In the meantime, you can use my [`class`](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class) custom binding to do the same thing. Both have the advantage of not clobbering any existing, static classes on the element. Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koviko/z7gj7/) demonstrating the `class` binding.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just use the css binding?

```
<ul id="MyList" data-bind="foreach:list">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: value, css: { height300Css: value >= 250 && value <= 300, height200Css: value >= 200 && value < 250 }"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

BTW I'm sure it's just pseudocode, but value can never be >= 300 AND <= 250, and you need to use && instead of 'and', so I changed the expressions for [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/zXcfx/1/) so 200-249 would be red and 250-300 would be blue.

Comment: Great solution but I had to accept the other solution as it's more mantainable.

Comment: This is a much better way to do it.  IMO